# Unable to understand one particular difference between Interface and abstract class in Java

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are interface method invocations slower than concrete invocations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839943/why-are-interface-method-invocations-slower-than-concrete-invocations)

I was going through a link describing difference between interface and abstract class. http://javapapers.com/core-java/abstract-and-interface-core-java-2/difference-between-a-java-interface-and-a-java-abstract-class/

There is one difference mentioned as below

> In comparison with java abstract classes, java interfaces are slow as it requires extra indirection.

Can someone please explain this point?

Comment: Link shared..Edited the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839943/why-are-interface-method-invocations-slower-than-concrete-invocations)