# in which scenario abstract class and interface should not be used?

Tags: java

I have been asked in interview ***in which scenario abstract class and interface both should not be used ?***

I wasn’t able to clearly answer his question with specific examples of when you would not want to do this, at the time. I have search lot for specific answer with example but unable to find.

***I know when to use which one.*** Also I understand that
***abstraction is a mechanism and practice to reduce and factor out details so that one can focus on a few concepts at a time.***

So can I answer that when I don't found any relation then i should not use it.

Can you genious guys spend a minute and answer me to increase my knowledge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that your interviewer does not understand what did he asked. Or you did not exactly understand him. Never mind: next interview will be more successful. Good luck.

Comment: When you don't need or won't have multiple implementations of something, just one.

Comment: Probably in strict cases where performance is very important (in interviewer mind at least). See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6839943/2252829

Comment: No, I think it has nothing to do with performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps when you explicitly want just one implementation, so that you don't maintain two versions of the same thing. One might also make the class `final` in this situation.

Comment: thanks. I think I got proper idea but can you give one example (Except final stuff) so that I can understand more briefly (If you can spare a minute more).

Comment: One example would be simple value classes like Strings, Money, Date. Often there is just nothing that you gain by creating interfaces or abstract classes.

Answer (score 3):

One anti-pattern that comes to mind is where constants (as public static final variables) are put on either an abstract class and an interface, and then the users of these constants implement the interface or extend the abstract class.  The so-called advantage of this was that the constants did not need to be qualified every time they were used.  e.g. `MyConstants.MY_VALUE` vs `MY_VALUE`

With Java 1.5 and later, static imports can now be used to avoid having to qualify the constant with a class name.  Though personally I don't really mind qualifying constants with a class name especially if the constants' class names have a meaningful 'grouping' name.

Answer (score 1):

I have one idea. Probably if your class contains a set of static utilities. For example `StringUtils`. But anyway I think that the question as you wrote it does not have too much sense.

Comment: Interesting, but it's also good to point out that Java 8 may have static interface methods. http://bit.ly/SH0PcH Regardless, this is probably what they had in mind!

Answer (score 0):

2 cases I think

1 : if you have to instantiate objects of your class (`eg: MyClass object=new MyClass()`)

2 : in case of inheritance of the same implementation as the parent class  eg:

```
class Parent {
    int x;

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = 2 * x;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int y = 1;

    public void setX_AND_Y(int x, int y) {
        setX(x); // same implmentaion
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with spring bean that had to implement interface and extend some base class in the past.

This was rather an advanced problem related to AOP and Spring, so I cannot be 100% sure that this is what your interviewer asked, but it is totally something you can stumble upon in the wild, and not limited only to Spring.

Often you want to add AOP to your Spring application (for example to use @Transactional annotations). The problem is that there are couple of ways how AOP can be implemented, from patching bytecode at compile time or loadtime, to generation something similar to wrappers at runtime.

The latter approach is the most cheap, build-structure-wise, and used more commonly than others but it has it's disadvantages.

One of them is that there are plenty of ways to do this and approach differ from what exact bean (class instance) you want to weave (wrap). Thing like "whether class implements interface", "whether class extends class" and combinations matter here.

I won't delve deep into details here, simply because I struggled with this pretty while ago, but you can get a grasp of what you'll have to deal with from [spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types) briefly discussing this matter.

I will say though that in my project things went wrong when I decided to add class that extended another class and implement some interface. It was quite a challenge to make things work, because you have to have really decent understanding of how Spring itself and AOP weaving techniques work and how to configure all these things so they work as expected.

**UPDATE:** Answering your question in one sentence: You probably do not want to extend abstract class and implement interface at the same time in the code that deals with dynamic class proxying/AOP/code generation.