# min heap java implementation arraylist vs array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, heap

So I'm working on project for my algorithms class that I'm currently taking. I'm doing some research online and see that some people are using an `ArrayList<Integer>` and some people are using an `int array[]`. My question is, what's better to use for a min heap and why. The project requires me to keep the top 10000 largest numbers in the list from a very large list of numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the array size at compile time, [using a bare `int[]` array is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389609/array-vs-arraylist-in-performance). Of course, the performance difference is probably negligible -- but the idea is that `ArrayList` is internally implemented as an `Object[]` array, so you're saving yourself that overhead, plus the overhead of dealing with `Integer` vs `int`.

Comment: Thanks for that. That's what I thought, since I know the size of the array needed it would be better to use a bare array. I was noticing that the array list was used for increasing the number of elements

Comment: Yeah, I think the primary benefit is the `add` method that gives you a dynamically-resizing array (which you could do yourself, but which is a lot of boilerplate to write). If you know your max size, and you don't need any of the other `ArrayList` convenience methods, I don't think there is a compelling reason to use one. Also, please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure **at all* that an ArrayList<Integer> wraps an int[]. It most like wraps an Object[] in which ints are autoboxed. Which implies 1) more memory consuptions (you'll have the `int`s AND the pointer to them), and 2) an autoboxing performance penalty. Granted, both may be negligeable at small sizes.

Comment: @PatrickCollins, not to be pedantic, but it's no Integer[] either ! It could not work with Generics if that was the case... It will create an Object[] which contains Integer instances, which is not the same as Integer[] (although memory wise, it is, it is practically different)

Comment: @GPI Won't these be initialized as `Integer[]` elements, and then possibly upcast to `Object[]`? Certainly they need to be initialized as `Integer`s if they're going to be `Integer`s later on, no?

Comment: Well : generics are erased at run time in java. The only thing that ties `new ArrayList<Integer>()` to an `Integer` is... a generic type. That does not exist at runtime. So the JVM has NO WAY of knowing it has to build a Integer[].

If you look at the code, array list has a `private transient Object[] elementData;` as its container, and that's it. When you call add(int), int is boxed to Integer, and you have elementData[position++] = yourInteger. (with other checks before)

Comment: Okay. I'm still not quite solid on my understanding of Java generics and so I'll avoid muddling it up any more, but if you'd like, feel free to edit my answer to more accurately reflect what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

An `int[]` will consume less memory than an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Part of that is simply the overhead which is added from an `Integer` which adds ~16 bytes per instance. This [video](http://www.techtalkshub.com/java-code-java-heap-understanding-memory-usage-application/) goes through memory impact of various objects and collections in 32bit and 64bit jvms. At about the 9:30 mark it talks about memory associated with each object. At about the 11:15 mark it talks about how much memory various types (including `Object` references) take.
For an `int[]`, you have 1 `Object` (the `int[]`) and it will actually contain all of the individual `int` values as contiguous memory.
For an `ArrayList<Integer>`, you have the `ArrayList` object, the `Object[]` object and all of the `Integer` objects. Additionally, the `Object[]` doesn't actually contain the `Integer` objects in contiguous memory, rather it contains object references in contiguous memory. The `Integer` objects themselves are elsewhere on the heap.

So the end result is that an `ArrayList<Integer>` requires ~6x the amount of memory as an `int[]`. The backing `Object[]` and the `int[]` take the same amount of memory (~40,000 bytes). The 10k `Integer` objects take ~20 bytes each for a total of 200,000 bytes. So the `ArrayList` will be a minimum of 240,000 bytes compared to the `int[]` at approximately 40,000 bytes.